# Escaping dollar sign in Terraform

Tags: terraform, hcl

In an attempt to create a route key named `$disconnect` for an API Gateway, I'm running the snippet below, while `var.route_name` should receive the string "disconnect":

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "route" {
  api_id    = var.apigw_api.id
  route_key = "$${var.route_name}"
  # more stuff...
}
```

But it's not escaping it correctly. I coulnd't find a proper way to emit a `$`, followed by `var.route_name`'s content.

How to do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In [Terraform's template language](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#string-templates), the sequence `$${` is the escape sequence for literal `${`, and so unfortunately in your example Terraform will understand `$${var.route_name}` as literally `${var.route_name}`, and not as a string interpolation at all.

To avoid this, you can use any strategy that causes the initial `$` to be separate from the following `${`, so that Terraform will understand the first `$` as a literal and the remainder as an interpolation sequence.

One way to do that would be to present that initial literal `$` via an interpolation sequence itself:

```
"${"$"}${var.route_name}"
```

The above uses an interpolation sequence that would *typically* be redundant -- its value is a literal string itself -- but in this case it's grammatically useful to change Terraform's interpretation of that initial dollar sign.

Some other permutations:

```
join("", ["$", var.route_name])
```

```
format("$%s", var.route_name)
```

```
locals {
  dollar = "$"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "route" {
  route_key = "${local.dollar}${var.route_name}"
  # ...
}
```

Again, all of these are just serving to present the literal `$` in various ways that avoid it being followed by either `{` or `${` and thus avoid Terraform's parser treating it as a template sequence or template escape.

Answer (score 3):

There probably exists an easier way to escape a `$` in hcl2 string interpolation, but the [format function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/format.html) will also assist you here:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "route" {
  api_id    = var.apigw_api.id
  route_key = format("$%s", var.route_name)
  # more stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to dynamically set a variable name (ie the variable name depends on another variable), this is not possible. Otherwise you could do this:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "route" {
  api_id    = var.apigw_api.id
  route_key = "$$${var.route_name}"
  # more stuff...
}
```

Instead, create a map `route_keys` and choose the key based on the name:

```
locals {
  route_keys = {
    route_name1 = ...
    route_name2 = ...
  }
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "route" {
  api_id    = var.apigw_api.id
  route_key = local.route_keys[var.route_name]
  # more stuff...
}
```