# How to inject a bash script with a dollar sign ($) in terraform?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a simple bash script that does something like the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
a=$(curl -s http://metadata/endpoint/internal)
echo "$a - bar"
```

(this is just a simplification). Note the use of the two `$` signs to execute a command and resolve a variable.

Using Terraform, I want to write this file to a GCP instance during startup. Per Terraform's instructions, I'm attempting to avoid using the [File Provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/file). Using the `metadata_startup_script` field in `google_compute_instance`[2](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance), I am including the script so that I can write it to a particular location.

E.g.

```bash
  metadata_startup_script = <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash -xe
sudo tee /etc/myservice/serv.conf > /dev/null <<EOI
${file("${path.module}/scripts/simple_bash.sh")}
EOI
EOF
```

Terraform is interpolating the `$` in the subscript *somewhere* (either in the loading into the metadata_startup_script, or in the writing out into the script to disk.

So, depending on what I use to try to escape the interpolation, it still fails to write. For example, I have tried (in the subscript):

```bash
echo "\$a - bar"
echo "${“$”}a - bar"
echo "$$a - bar"
```

According to the terraform docs, I'm supposed to use `$$`, but when I do it in the above, I get:

```bash
echo "1397a - bar"
```

All which fail to replicate the original script.

I’m just looking for the exact bash script, as written, to be written to disk.

My goal would be to do the above without extra escape sequences (as detailed here - [Escaping dollar sign in Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66953938/escaping-dollar-sign-in-terraform)) so that i can continue to run the original script (for debugging purposes).

I would also prefer not to build a packer image with the original script in it.

Thanks!

Comment: Trying to ask the same question again I see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72596790/including-a-bash-script-that-has-in-it-in-terraform).  No point asking over and over and get the same responses - closure.  Modify the question, provide more details.  I am not one that closed it, but posting the exact same question will not help you get more answers.

Comment: Per the instructions, i reworded it, added more details and reposted. I followed the instructions!

Comment: I changed the initial example, added more clarity about the provisioners i was using and the stated goal, and followed EXACTLY what the instructions said (https://share.cleanshot.com/FZr77p). I still have the problem, and the Terraform docs are still wrong. Please let me know what I can add more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's *Terraform* eating your variable interpolations here, because Terraform only understands `${` (a dollar sign followed by a brace) as starting an interpolation, whereas your example contains only `$a`.

However, you do seem to be embedded one bash script inside another, so it seems plausible to me that the outer bash is resolving your `$a` before the inner bash gets a chance to look at it. If so, you can use the *literal* variant of bash heredoc syntax, as described in answers to *[How to cat <> a file containing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697688/how-to-cat-eof-a-file-containing-code)*, so that the outer bash will take the content as literal and leave it to the inner bash to evaluate.

```
  metadata_startup_script = <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash -xe
sudo tee /etc/myservice/serv.conf > /dev/null <<'EOI'
${file("${path.module}/scripts/simple_bash.sh")}
EOI
EOF
```

Notice that I wrote `<<'EOI'` instead of `<<EOI`, following the guidance from that other question in combination with [the main Bash documentation on "here documents"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) (bold emphasis mine):

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only *word* (with no trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input (or file descriptor *n* if *n* is specified) for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>         here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or filename expansion is performed on *word*. **If any part of *word* is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on *word*, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.** If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and `\` must be used to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.
>
> If the redirection operator is `<<-`, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing *delimiter*. This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

---

If your machine image is configured to run [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) at startup -- this is *often* but not always what is responsible for executing `metadata_startup_script` -- you may be able to achieve a similar effect without so much Bash scripting indirection by using [Cloud Config YAML](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html) instead of a shell script directly.

For example, if your intent is only to write the content of that file into the designated location in the filesystem, you could potentially follow [the *Writing out arbitrary files* example](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#writing-out-arbitrary-files):

```
  metadata_startup_script = <<-EOF
    #cloud-config
    ${yamlencode({
      write_files = [
        {
          encoding    = "b64"
          content     = filebase64("${path.module}/scripts/simple_bash.sh")
          path        = "/etc/myservice/serv.conf"
          owner       = "root:root"
          permissions = "0644"
        },
      ]
    }}
  EOF
```

Cloud-init evaluates [its modules](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html) at various points in the startup lifecycle. [The *Write Files* module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#write-files) used here is specified to run once on the first boot of an instance, which matches how Cloud-init would typically treat a naked shell script too.

Comment: terrific detail, thank you so much! 

This ALSO explains why I was getting a value ('1397') instead of something nil -> it was giving me the PID. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think your issue is related to TF interpolation. I think you have problems because of normal `bash` interpolation, as its `bash` which is going to try to resolve `$` in your `/etc/myservice/serv.conf` while writing its content.

The regular solution is to use `'EOI'`, not `EOI`:

```
  metadata_startup_script = <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash -xe
sudo tee /etc/myservice/serv.conf > /dev/null <<'EOI'
${file("${path.module}/scripts/simple_bash.sh")}
EOI
EOF
```

Comment: I wish i could accept you both :) But this was exactly it!

Comment: @aronchick No problem. Glad it got sorted out.